# Non portable pointer assignment in main

Tags: c, pointers

In the book "Understanding pointers in C" there are some solved problems after an argument has been explained. Page  22, problem N.5
I am going to attach the code and the explanation. After that, there will be my question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *c;
    c = check(10, 20);
    printf("c = %p\n",c);
    return 0;
}

int * check(int i, int j)
{
    int *p, *q;
    p = &i;
    q = &j;
    if(i >= 45)
    {
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        return q;
    }
}
```

Output:
Error message: Non portable pointer assignment in main

> Explanation The reason for the error is simple. The integers being
>   passed to check( ) are collected in i and j, and then their addresses
>   are assigned to p and q. Then in the next statement the value of i is
>   tested against 45, and either the address stored in p or the address
>   stored in q is returned. It appears that this address would be
>   collected in c in main( ), and then would he printed out. And there
>   lies the error. The function check( ) is not capable of returning an
>   integer pointer. All that it can return is an ordinary integer. Thus
>   just declaring c as an integer pointer is not sufficient. We must make
>   the following modifications in the program to make it work properly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * check(int, int);

int main()
{
    int *c;
    c = check(10, 20);
    printf("c = %p\n",c);
    return 0;
}
int *check(int i, int j)
{
    ......
    ......
}
```

In my opinion this does not make sense.
The author, to make an error on purpose on the first piece of code, tries to use in the main, a pointer that points to a memory area that is not allocated.
But the way he "tries" to fix the problem is not correct at all, he did not change anything! Instead he should have malloc'd some memory areas in check() function. Am I correct?

Comment: The Kanetkar books are notoriously bad and should be avoided at all costs - unfortunately they are still widely used in Indian colleges despite the poor quality and the fact that they are at least 20 years out of date.

Comment: If you tweak your compiler to [give you all the warnings it can](http://ideone.com/GUKtRd) and treat every warning as an error, you will never face such problems.

Comment: @Caterpillar What I had cautioned you about YK?

Comment: Burn that book. Not only does Yashavant Kanetkar write non-portable garbage, but he has refused to fix it in past releases. In an industry prone to significant changes, an author and teacher should be willing to admit that he/she is wrong and make changes to avoid misleading people. Before you buy a new book, make sure it's up-to-date and written by a *reputable* author.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue The funny thing is the OP is from Italy.Seems like the Kanetkar scam has reached Europe too!!

Comment: @SheerFish Shall we brainstorm ways to defeat Kanetkar in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28724/room-for-modifiable-lvalue-and-sheer-fish)?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Sorry I was away when you posted that message.I would love to chat with you someday.Not about that author essentially.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is really about the *default return value* of a function that hasn't been declared yet. In your first example, when the compiler sees the line `c = check(10, 20);` it doesn't yet know what this function will return. The standard says the compiler should then assume that the return is an `int`. And this is what this is all about: the size of an `int` may be different than the size of a `int *` (a pointer). To make the compiler always emit the correct machine code for this it must know that `check` returns a pointer which is why it needs to be declared. That's what the second example does: it tells the compiler *"there will be a function named 'check' and it will look like this"*.

Apart from that, the example is really bad. The arguments to `check` are pushed on the stack and then the function returns pointers to these stack locations. But it's not guaranteed that these stack locations are valid any more after the function exits. This is *undefined behaviour* which means the compiler is allowed to do anything it likes, even make your computer explode. This specific example should actually work as it's only printing the *pointer* (that is, the address it is pointing to) but it is not actually *dereferencing* it (this is, reading from the address the pointer points to). On most machines/compilers even dereferencing should work "correctly" but you may not rely on it.

Comment: Implementation dependent? No. Undefined behaviour? Yes.

Comment: Since when is undefined behaviour not implementation dependent (in what it's actually doing)? ;-P But I'll clarify this more.

Comment: An implementation is required to document implementation-defined behaviour, but not undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no function prototype before the first usage of the function, compiler assumes that function returns `int`.

So the compiler assume that you are assigning an `int` variable to `int*`. The size of the `int` and `int*` may be different, depending on the platform and compiler.

For example there are embedded systems that have the same type for unsigned integers and pointers, so in the code you in both cases will see `uint32_t`.

Comment: _Dereferencing_ the pointer will lead to undefined behavior, just printing it out is not.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, adding the prototype only fixes the compiler warning/error but not the problem that the `check` function will return a pointer to a local variable.

However, it's not undefined behavior until you try to dereference the returned pointer. Just printing it out is okay.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issue.

1. Returning address of local variable.

   This scnario is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer. When the `Check()` execution is completed, the memory allocated for the local variable may be allocated to some other function. so accessing that memory leads to undefined results.
2. Needs forward declaration. By default return type will be considered as `int`, but here `int*` is used. so adding `int * check(int, int);` will solve `Error message: Non portable pointer assignment in main`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main "point" of the code is to tell you that undeclared functions have a return type that defaults to `int`. Which is true.

However the code is flawed beyond that, because the `check` function returns a pointer to a local variable (the parameter `i` or `j`, depending on `i`'s value), which is an undefined behavior (thankfully, that pointer is never dereferenced).

Answer (score 1):

You are returning addresses of local variables that allocate at stack of the `check()` function.
when the `check()` function ended so the function stack, you can't return address to variables that not exist any more!

You can change the code to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * check(int* i, int* j);
int main()
{
    int *c;
    int n1,n2;
    n1=10;
    n2=20;
    c = check(&n1, &n2);
    printf("c = %p\n",c);
    return 0;
}

int * check(int* i, int* j)
{
    int *p, *q;
    p = i;
    q = j;
    if((*i) >= 45)
    {
        return p;
    }

    return q;

}
```

Comment: You're missing the _default int return type_ issue. So without the declaring `check` first this is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning addresses of local variables. Dereferencing those is `undefined`behavior in C. Both `p` and `q` are pointers to the local variables of the function `check()`.After the function `check()` returns control to `main()`, then `p` and `q` point to undefined values.Further,do make this following correction to your code:

```
printf("c = %p\n",(void*)c);
```

Hey Caterpillar,I had warned you about that author's book,didn't I? :-)

**Edit** You forgot the function declaration for `check()` before `main()`.In my compiler it always throws a warning message.Add the following before the main() function :

```
int *check(int,int);
```

Comment: _Dereferencing_ the pointer will lead to undefined behavior, just printing it out is not.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Indeed, but it still laxes the OP into believing it's ok to return addresses of local variables.Given that I have answered his questions before and aware that he is  new to the whole thing,he may vary as well dereference it.

Comment: Yes, its true, but that's not the reason why the error message was shown.